# Doubly Linked List in C++ (Pointer being freed was not allocated)

Tags: c++, pointers, linked-list, dynamic-memory-allocation, doubly-linked-list

Can someone please tell me where I'm going wrong here? I believe the issue is with the clear() function but am not entirely sure. The goal is the create a doubly linked list. I still need to add some functionality, but feel that i've added enough to run what i've supplied in the main().

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

template <class T>
class doubLList;

template <class T>
class doubNode{
    T data;
    doubNode<T>* next;
    doubNode<T>* prev;
public:
    doubNode(T data = T(), doubNode<T>* prev = nullptr, doubNode<T>* next = nullptr) : data(data),
    next(next), prev(prev) {}
    friend doubLList<T>;
    T& returnData() {return data;}
    doubNode<T>*& returnNext() {return next;}
};

template <class T>
class doubLList{
    doubNode<T>* head;
    doubNode<T>* tail;
public:
    doubLList() {head = new doubNode<T>; tail = new doubNode<T>; head->next = tail; tail->prev = head; cout<< "constructed" << endl;}
    doubLList(const doubLList<T>& copy);
    ~doubLList();
    doubLList<T>& operator=(const doubLList<T>& rhs);
    void clear();
    void insert(const T& data) {head->next = new doubNode<T>(data, head->next, head); head->next->next->prev = head->next;}
    doubNode<T>*& returnHead() {return head;}
};


template <class T>
void doubLList<T>::clear(){
    cout << "Clear" << endl;
    while(head->next != tail){
        cout << "Run" << endl;
        doubNode<T>* delNode = head->next;
        head->next = delNode->next;
        head->next->prev = head;
        delete delNode;
    }
}

template <class T>
doubLList<T>::doubLList(const doubLList<T>& copy){
    head = new doubNode<T>;
    tail = new doubNode<T>;
    head->next = tail;
    tail->prev = head;
    *this = copy;
}

template <class T>
doubLList<T>& doubLList<T>::operator=(const doubLList<T>& rhs) {
    if(this == &rhs){
        return *this;
    }
    clear();
    doubNode<T>* rhsPtr = rhs->next;
    while(rhs->next->next){
        tail->prev = new doubNode<T>(rhsPtr->data, tail, tail->prev);
        tail->prev->prev->next = tail->prev;
        rhsPtr = rhsPtr->next;
    }
}

template <class T>
doubLList<T>::~doubLList(){
    clear();
    delete head;
    delete tail;
    head = nullptr;
    tail = nullptr;
}



int main() {
    doubLList<int>test;

    cout << test.returnHead() << endl;

    test.insert(1);

    return 0;
}
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: The default constructor and destructor are not great. Copy constructor is not great. You need to draw these out, step-by-step. Uninitialized pointers and memory leaks abound.

Comment: `void insert(const T& data)` -- Where are you inserting the new data?  At the end of the list?  At the beginning of the list?  Also, the implementation of that function looks highly suspicious.  An insertion routine would usually traverse the list, while your code doesn't do that at all.  If not that, the `tail` would be used to figure out where to insert at the end -- again, your function doesn't do that.

Comment: Also, if `insert` actually inserts at the back of the list using the `tail` pointer for assistance, then I suggest you rewrite your copy constructor to simply call `insert` in a loop (once `insert` is working).  That would have been far easier to do than what you're doing now.

Comment: `head->next = new doubNode<T>(data, head->next, head)` in `insert` is really confusing. Why the `next`'s `next` is `head`? Your `doubNode` ctor takes `prev` as second one and `next` as third one.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie `insert()` doesn't need to traverse if you are tracking the tail. Other points are valid.

Comment: Then that makes this very easy: `doubLList<T>::doubLList(const doubLList<T>& copy){
    auto ptr = copy.head; while (ptr) { insert(ptr->data); ptr = ptr->next; } }` -- that would be the copy constructor, nice and easy.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie data is inserted to the front of the list.

Comment: @ilikemath3.14 So what is the purpose of the `tail` pointer?  You might as well remove it if you aren't going to use it, or at least write a function that inserts at the back of the list and use `tail`.  A doubly-linked list without a tail pointer has the last element as `nullptr` (that's the usual implementation), and not introduce another pointer to the class that serves no purpose.

Comment: *I still need to add some functionality,* -- You need to write an `insert` function that adds to the end of the list.  That would have automatically made your copy constructor and assignment operators cleaner, as all they would do is simply call that function.

Comment: OP, your new nodes are not going to the front of the list if you're assigning them to `head->next`. They're going to `head->next`, which is the second spot in the list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following offered the correct implementation:

Changed

```
doubNode(T data = T(), doubNode<T>* prev = nullptr, doubNode<T>* next = nullptr) : data(data),
    next(next), prev(prev) {}
```

to

```
doubNode(T data = T(), doubNode<T>* next = nullptr, doubNode<T>* prev = nullptr) : data(data),
    next(next), prev(prev) {}
```